# Client Certificates in Dotnet Core on Ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, ssl, asp.net-core

all - I've written a dotnet core API set that functions perfectly on windows. On Ubuntu 14.04, everything works except for one SOAP request to a vendor that uses a client certificate for authentication.

The request always times out. A Netstat trace shows that only 1 byte of data was sent to the remote service on 443. No communication happens for 100 seconds and then the app throws a timeout exception.

I've tried using openssl to export PEM and CRT files and referenced those in addition to the way the code is configured now (pfx w/ password). I've also loaded the certificate portions of the PFX into ca-certs.

Here's the code:

```
        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

        var baseAddress = new Uri(mySettings.ClientUrl);
        factory = new ChannelFactory<SingleSignOnSoap>(binding, new EndpointAddress(baseAddress));
        if (RuntimeEnvironment.OperatingSystemPlatform == Platform.Windows)
        {
            //windows file location
            factory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(mySettings.PrivateKeyWindowsPath, mySettings.PfxPass);
        }
        else
        {
            //linux file location
            factory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(mySettings.ClientPrivateKeyUnixPath, mySettings.PfxPass);

        }

        serviceProxy = factory.CreateChannel();
        RequestTicketRequest request = new RequestTicketRequest();
        RequestTicketRequestBody requestBody = new RequestTicketRequestBody(xmlRequest);
        request.Body = requestBody;

        RequestTicketResponse response = serviceProxy.RequestTicket(request);

        return response.Body.RequestTicketResult;
```

Comment: I didn't include it in the code, but the url does use https://

Comment: Also tried using BasicHttpsBinding to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wireshark and Tshark show the authentication is actually working ok. The timeout is happening because the ServiceFactory is waiting to receive the response, but the network has sent a connection reset flag ([RST, ACK]) to the remote server. I've been able to reproduce on multiple linux distros so I'm adding an issue to the dotnet core WCF team's queue on github.